# Remove space from mount point name

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, mountpoint

Hi in my ubuntu I have partioned my hard drive. and now I see the my mount point names contains space. please tell me how to remove the spaces from the name.
now it is like Local Disk 1, Local Disk 2 etc.  I just want to remove the space. Please see the image[image]
I want to do it for /dev/sda5 , /dev/sda6, /dev/sda7.
Please help me, due to this non of my web apps are working when I do image and video uploads.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually edit your `/etc/fstab`. It defines all your mount points. There are some GUIs for this, but I don't know any. You may find one yourself.

The syntax is: FILE_SYSTEM MOUNT_POINT TYPE OPTIONS DUMP PASS

Example for your `/dev/sda5`, append this line to your `/etc/fstab` and reboot:

```
/dev/sda5 /media/logan/LocalDisk1 ntfs-3g defaults,rw  0  0
```

If it's not mounted correctly create the folder first:

```
mkdir /media/logan/LocalDisk1
```

If it's working repeat it for your other partitions.

I sometimes have permission problems with NTFS partitions after mounting. I hope you will not.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below steps.

```
sudo umount /dev/sda5
sudo mkdir /media/logan/LocalDisk1
sudo mount /dev/sda5/ /media/logan/LocalDisk1
```

For persistent, you can make fstab entry. Repeat this for all volumes.

Comment: I think s/he does not mean the label.

Comment: yes I didnt mean lebel, I changed the label but its of no effect.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice it properly. I have edited my answer. Thank You.